# Authorization filter not working in my mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, filter

I am new to learn filters in mvc. I create a Authorization filter in my project.

**Accountcontroller**

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Account/

        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Logins()
        {
            string username = Request["username"];
            string password = Request["password"];
            Session.Add("username", username);
            Session.Add("password", password);

            return Redirect("/Home");
        }

    }

    public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {  
        void IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            try
            {
                string username = HttpContext.Current.Session["username"].ToString();
                string password = HttpContext.Current.Session["password"].ToString();

                if (username == password)
                {

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/Home");

                }
                else
                {

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/Account/login");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/Account/login");
            }
        }

    }
```

**Homecontroller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        [CustomAuthorization]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

    }
```

But now i am checking same string as username and password when i run this project if the username and password is correct home page is reloading again and again.

Comment: if username and password are correct then it will load the index (default action) action in homecontroller because you write HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/Home");

Comment: But it does not go to home index. Home page in redirect loop.

Comment: Is this intentional? 'if (username == password)'

Comment: I am just checking in future i will change this code.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit from Authorization attribute and override default behavior
Simple implementation would be like this

```
public class OptionalAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

public OptionalAuthorizeAttribute()
{

}

protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContext httpContext){
            string username = HttpContext.Current.Session["username"].ToString();
            string password = HttpContext.Current.Session["password"].ToString();

            if (username == password)
            {
                return true;
            }
                return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

And then you could override behavior of AuthorizeAttribute.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext)

Side note: I wrote this answer from mobile phone, so please double check for syntax errors when pasting to visual studio